# VBA - Late Binding vs. Early Binding Error - Difference in xml responses

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

I wrote some code to GET a response from a server using early binding (first statement when mbEARLY_BINDING_FSO = True

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module


#Const mbEARLY_BINDING_FSO = False
Private Const msMODULE_NAME As String = "Controls"

Public Sub refresh_database()

Const sPROC_NAME As String = "refresh_database()"
If Not gbDEBUG Then On Error GoTo errExitLL

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'LOWER LEVEL PROCEDURE

'Comments: Refresh the database from call to app.longtrend.com/api/seach?map=tickers
'Agurments: None
'Dependencies: None
'Returns: JSON object of available companies listed to Company List sheet
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Dim base_url As String
Dim successMsg As Variant
Dim Json As Object
Dim account_key As Variant
Dim dict_key As Variant
Dim item As Variant
Dim sheet_ticker As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim lcol As Long
Dim rng As Range

#If mbEARLY_BINDING_FSO Then
    Dim xml_obj As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set xml_obj = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
#Else
    Dim xml_obj As Object
    Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
#End If

Set sheet_ticker = Sheets("Admin_Control")

       UserFormProgress.Display 5, False
       UserFormProgress.SetText "Checking stuff XX ..."
       Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#

base_url = "https://app.longtrend.com/api/search?map=tickers"

'Open a new get request using URL
xml_obj.Open bstrMethod:="GET", bstrURL:=base_url
xml_obj.send

'set up the object and parse the response
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xml_obj.responseText)

' Status code router - 200 is Success, all else will print error in range("STATUS") and exit sub
If xml_obj.Status <> 200 Then
    With Range("STATUS")
        .Value = xml_obj.Status & ": " & Json("Error")
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 143, 143)
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End
End If

'Parse Json object
Dim i As Long
Dim key As Variant

i = rng.Row + 1
For Each key In Json
    sheet_ticker.Cells(i, rng.Column) = key
    sheet_ticker.Cells(i, rng.Column + 1) = Json(key)("name")
    sheet_ticker.Cells(i, rng.Column + 2) = Json(key)("sector")
    sheet_ticker.Cells(i, rng.Column + 3) = Json(key)("industry")
    sheet_ticker.Cells(i, rng.Column + 4) = Json(key)("marketCap")
    sheet_ticker.Cells(i, rng.Column + 5) = Json(key)("lastFY")
    i = i + 1
Next

Exit Sub
errExitLL:
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       ErrorHandling.LowLevel msMODULE_NAME, sPROC_NAME, "url", base_url, "last row", lrow

End Sub
```

With early binding, my xml_obj response is as exptected. The responseText stores all values to be parsed in the JSON converter. Now, prior to release I'd like to set to late binding. I've created the object as shown in the second statement however the responseText in the locals window says: *this method cannot be called until the send method has been called*. The xml_obj is sent prior to this local response.

I have tried the following so far:

```
Set xml_obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP60")
Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
```

To no avail! An error occur either when I attempt to create the object *CreateObject(XX)* and there is no associated ActiveX available, or as mentioned above, the response request isn't correct once the request is sent. I'm not sure what I'm missing as this should be a simple enough activity. Any help is much appreciated.

Running Office 365 (build 14228) for Windows (64 bit, VBA7)

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Might be useful to include the part of your code where the error is raised.

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams I clarified above.

Comment: Does it actually error when you try to access the `ResponseText` property in your code?  Are you sure you've actually called the `Send` method?

Comment: Hi Tim, I believe the error is with the response itself. After I `xml_obj.send` I use a JSON converter to parse the `xml_obj.responseText'. Under late binding, there is no response object to parse. In the Locals window my xml_obj responseBody, responseStream, responseText, etc., all say: <this method cannot be called until the send method has been called>. I think the important bit here is that everything works well under early binding. Very strange. Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Comment: It would be useful to see the whole code, from where the object is instantiated to where you try to access the `ResponseText` property.   If it's telling you that it's not available because the request hasn't been sent then that seems a good place to start troubleshooting.  When I tried a short test method using late binding I had to problems accessing `ResponseText`, so likely it's something specific to your code.

Comment: No problem @Tim, updated above

Comment: Does removing the parameter names from the call to `xml_obj.Open` help? Try just using `xml_obj.Open "GET", base_url`

Comment: If you don't specify a value, then the third argument to `Open` (asynchronous) defaults to `True`, so you should pass `False` there.  If you run asynchronously your code will not wait until the response is complete.

Comment: I can't believe it - that worked. Thank you both for your help, I had no idea about this default to true. Remarkable that these differences exist when using early/late binding. I will mark resolved. Thanks again

Comment: I'd find it difficult to believe it's due only to early vs. late binding - it defaults to the same value in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a value, then the third argument to `Open` (asynchronous) defaults to `True`, so you should pass `False` there.

If you run asynchronously your code will not wait until the response is complete.